# Confidence interval for independent variable of a linear regression model in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, confidence-interval

Let's assume a dataset the contains single time steps (in seconds) and a distance (in m) a runner managed each time step:

```
time <- c(300,600,900) # time in sec
dist <- c(1050,1950,3100) # dist in m
```

Here a plot to illustrate it:

```
plot(x=time,y=dist,xlim=c(0,1800),ylim=c(0,5000))
```

Based on a zero-intercept (assuming no distance at time 0) linear regression model one can evaluate how the distance is related to the time, i.e. one can calculate the speed of the runner.

```
lm1 <- lm(dist~0+time)
abline(lm1,col="red")
```

In addition, also the confidence interval for that specific linear model can easily be predicted and plotted:

```
new_time <- seq(0,2000)
prd <- predict(lm1,newdata=data.frame(time=new_time),interval = c("confidence"),level = 0.90,type="response")
lines(new_time,prd[,"lwr"],col="red",lty=2)
lines(new_time,prd[,"upr"],col="red",lty=2)
```

[image: Plot:Dist_Vs_Time]

However, I am interested when a certain distance will be reached by the runner? For example I want to know when a runner passes the 5000 m. Of course, the mean time can be extracted/calculated from the regression coefficient:

```
5000/(coef(lm1))[["time"]]
```

But how can I get the corresponding confidence intervals, i.e. at which time do the lines of the confidence intervals in the plot cross the dist=5000 m line?

Comment: bootstrap or delta method ...

Comment: Check the delta method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). In your case I think the variance of `time` would be something like `((-5000/(coef(lm1)^2))*(summary(lm1)$coef[,2]))^2`